# MAX_SUPPLY on a smart contract shown on the site is different than the one being pulled from Python requests module, why?

Tags: python

I am trying to pull the MAX_SUPPLY from this Ethereum smart contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0xce25e60a89f200b1fa40f6c313047ffe386992c3#readContract). As of 2021-11-11, the value shown on the site is `4670`.

I am trying to pull it using the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://etherscan.io/address/0xce25e60a89f200b1fa40f6c313047ffe386992c3#readContract'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = requests.get(url)

print(result.content.decode())
```

However I am getting this `uint256 public MAX_SUPPLY = 4360;`, which seems to be an old value. How can I extract the most up-to-date value?

Answer (score 0):

The `uint256 public MAX_SUPPLY = 4360` is the initial value of `MAX SUPPLY` (assuming it is not changed in the constructor). In the same contract, there is a function called `setMaxTokenSupply` that can change the state of `MAX_SUPPLY`, which is why the the current `MAX_SUPPLY` is different on Etherscan than what the initial value was in the source code. To get the current value of a public variable in Solidity, just call the variable as if it were a function. Using Brownie for example, you could read the value like this: `contract.MAX_SUPPLY()`